# If you have a uid of user B as the value of a child under uid A, how do you check the value of B in a write security rule?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

```
JSON:

people
  uid1 
    peopleWhoLike 
        childbyAutoID:uid5
        childbyAutoID: uid6
        childbyAutoID: uid10
     domain
         @aol.com
```

This is how the user B uids are created in the code (he is `auth.auth().currentUser!.uid`):

```
 let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid] 
ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) –
```

To check user B (like uid5 for example) under user A(uid1), would you use something like $peopleWhoLike for the write rules, or where would you define it?

Basically I need a placeholder for uid5, uid10, uidd6 or whoever wants to write there. I need to know what to use as the placeholdder and how to define it in my code. Once I know that, I can make a write rule that checks (a) if the person writing has the same domain as the user he writes to (uid5 writing to uid1 for example), and (b) that the person who writes can only write his own uid there. For example uid5 can only write uid5 in there, not uid6. The rule would look as follows, with X being the placeholder:

```
"X" == auth.uid && data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == newData.child('domain').val()
```

Multiple likes under peopeWhoLike are allowed, but only if 24 hours have passed. Part of the code checks via snapshot if there was one in the last 24 hours and only registers entries if there were none.

Comment: That's a little vague; what does 'check the value' mean exactly? Check to see if it's.... a string? A number? Greater than 42? Exists? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Jay By check I mean 'evaluate'. In other words, to make sure that write access should be granted. For example check if uid5 is the auth.uid. I just need to know how to make a rule for what uid 5 uid 6 and uid 10 is allowed to be. In other words, rule to apply to the nodes like (uid5, uid6, uid10) not the entire peopleWhoLike

Comment: The problem is there has to be other data involved in that rule.  In other words, if you want only uid5, uid6, and uid10 to be allowed to write to the *uid1/peopleWhoLike* me node, you can simply do a comparison to see if the auth is one of those users - but that is essentially hard coding the user id's that can access that node, which I don't think is what you want.  For example what's to allow/prevent uid2 to writing to the peopleWhoLike me node? *

Comment: yeah. It shouldn't just be those three users. I'm just trying to figure out how to write a rule for the nodes of peopleWhoLike and not the entire peopleWhoLike, so that a user can write for only himself and not all the others. In my case to be precise, I want to check the following: `write: "X" == auth.uid && 
            data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == newData.child('domain').val()` In other words, the node has write access if the user (say uid500) is authenticated user and has a domain child that is equal to the domain child of the uid1

Comment: In my instance, I need to figure out what to make X, perhaps $peopleWhoLike, but I am not sure if I need to define that somewhere. X being a value for all those who can write (make node) under peopleWhoLike of uid1

Comment: That's a bit more clear but the *question* needs to be updated or it will likely be closed. As you can see by your comment *and has a domain child*, we don't know what a *domain child* is because it's not included in the question. Also, *what to make X* - rules  evaluate to true or false, so only two choices. *auth.uid* is the currently logged in users uid, so what's the relevance `"X" == auth.uid` in your comment? Are you comparing that to something else? If you want the user to be authenticated, it's this pattern `auth.uid != null`. Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: `I’ll update the question. I didn’t add it originally cause it is not really what I need to fix. `"X" == auth.uid`  is there to make sure that a user can only write his own node/uid under `peopleWhoLike` after the `childbyAutoID`. For example, say `uid5` wants to write, he can only add `uid5` there, not `uid6`.

Comment: As for `X`, that is what I really need to figure out. I need `X` to be a placeholder for `uid5`, uid6, uid10 or whoever else wants to write there in - write: "X" == auth.uid &&   data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == newData.child('domain').val()

Comment: To circle back around on this; if you want to only allow another user to write *their specific uid*, you're going to need a validation rule to validate the data being written is in fact, their uid. The downside is revealed by your proposed structure; since you're using .childByAutoId, meaning each key is unique, a nefarious user could write their own uid 10000 times within that node. A better and safer bet would be to leverage the users uid as the key, with a value of true. That will simplify the rules, by denying a write to anything but their own uid, and prevent multiple nodes being written.

Comment: @Jay that is a good point. I wanted to use the `childByAutoID` for analysis later on.  Say I remove it, how would I be able to make sure that the user can only add his own uid there. Keep in mind, multiple likes are allowed, but only if 24 hours have passed. Part of the code checks via snapshot if there was one in the last 24 hours and only registers entries if there were none.

Comment: Let me pose the question this way 'the objective is to only allow writing to a node if the key they are writing to matches their uid' That process is touched on in the documentation and there are dozens of questions here about that as well. There's isn't going to be one answer as there are a lot of other variables. *but only if 24 hours have passed* segues into an entirely different question & answer so that should be separated from this initial question (multiple questions within one are OT for SO).

Comment: what does OT for SO mean?yeah only with 24 hour included would it work

Comment: Off Topic for StackOverflow. Often times when a question is either too vague or has too many questions within the question it's considered Off Topic and will be closed as *Needing More Focus*. See [Why Questions are Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). So just trying to keep the question focused to prevent it from being closed.

Comment: thanks. In that case it may be a better idea for me to close the question and ask a more specific one. But then you won't get points for it and you've spent a lot of time in the comments with me. I do appreciate that. I'll look at it again in the morning.

Comment: Meh, not concerned about points - more important that the question is clear and answerable. It wouldn't matter anyway as I would have to post an answer and I am not sure how to answer this particular question. So yes, create a question that is specific and be sure to include code that duplicates the issue with a clear explanation.

Comment: @Jay Thanks. Was out for a week with eye surgery. I created one here that I think better gets at the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814663/write-rules-for-childbyautoid-in-firebase-realtime-database