# Write Rules for ChildByAutoID in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

JSON:

```
  "people" : {
    “user uid” : {
      “**Domain** : "aol.com",
      "peopleWhoLike: {
        "-M-vZavBdcpX3SzkvgKN" : "**IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1**", ////this is autokey: uid of the likeR///
    }
  }
```

Let us say you want to evaluate IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1. If he were not proceeded by childByAutoID, I'd use this:

```
,"peopleWhoLike" : {
"$peopleWhoLike_id": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "$peopleWhoLike_id == auth.uid && data.parent().parent().child('domain').val() == data.parent().parent().parent().child(newData.val()).child('domain').val()"
} /////checks domain of like with domain of person he likes, and makes sure only he can write for himself.
```

This would be fine if IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1 stood without the ChildByAutoID, however it does not. So now I am thinking I need to use something like $ChildByAutoID, but am not sure what to call it because it is not explicitly defined in the JSON.

Source for security rules I read through for $ variables: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding another answer that specifically addresses the rules part of the question

The goal is to only allow a write to a people node if the domain in that node matches the current users domain node. I won't write all of the rules but this will be the first step:

The structure would be

```
people
   uid_0
      domain: "aol.com"
   uid_1
      domain: "gmail.com"
users
   uid_2
      domain: "aol.com"
   uid_3
      domain: "aol.com"
```

The rules would be something like

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
      ".write": false,
        "people": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "root.child('people').child($uid).child('domain').val() === 
                       root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('domain').val()" 
          }
        }
  }
}
```

The write will be allowed if the value at
/people/uid_x/domain = /users/this_uid/domain

With the above structure, users uid_2 and uid_3 can write to people/uid_0 but not to people/uid_1

Comment: Thanks. My structure has only people not users, so I altered that in the rule, but it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to childByAutoId within peoplWhoLikeMe in this use case, and it further complicates the rules.

You know the specific data you want to store, so just store that data with a placeholder for the value.

In other words, I assume you're storing users UID's so your structure would be

```
people
   this_users_uid
      domain: "aol.com"
      people_who_like_me
          uid_0: true
          uid_3: true
```

That simplifies the rules dramatically as when another user writes to the people_who_like_me node, just validate the key being written is their own uid. It also guarantees uniqueness so child nodes are never duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only issue with that is that duplicate likes are allowed under certain instances (in next day for example), so if uid_0 liked it twice over two days, the two entries would not be distinguishable from one another

Comment: @franktimmon So a user could like another user 1000 times? That seems odd.

Comment: yes, but that would have to happen over a period of roughly 3 years. In context it makes sense, but yeah I get that it is not the norm

Comment: @franktimmon So what rules are you trying to enforce? Since a user can write unlimited data to a node, what rule are you looking for?

Comment: I want to make sure that the user is the current user and that one of his other childs(Domain) matches the Domain child of the user he is writing to